# GWT 2.8.2 not compiling javax.xml.bind.annotation anymore

Tags: java, gwt, javax.xml

I am using javax.xml.bind in my entities for xml serialization and it compiled fine until gwt 2.8.1, but with 2.8.2 version, the compiler fails at annotations like javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement with message that there is no source code available for javax.xml.bind.

```
[ERROR] Hint: Your source appears not to live underneath a subpackage called 'client'; no problem, but you'll need to use the <source> directive in your module to make it accessible
...
      [ERROR] Line 3: The import javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved
      [ERROR] Line 11: XmlRootElement cannot be resolved to a type
```

I did not find anything related to this in gwt release notses
(http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_2)

I am using JDK 8:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 8 [1.8.0_172]">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It seems that you're using a JDK9/10/11, where `javax.xml` is removed. You need to declare the dependency explicitly. See <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j> Not sure if the same problem, though.

Comment: I am using jdk 8. I have edited my post.

Comment: I do not have an answer "why" this has happened. We are also using JDK8, but adding dependency to `jaxb-api` solved the problem.